# how to disable mac os Sonoma reactions?

Tags: javascript, macos, webrtc

is it possible to disabled use reactions in web-webrtc app in browser? https://support.apple.com/en-asia/HT212950

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details about what you want to do and what you have tried so far.  In general though, no something in a web browser is not allow to change any OS-level settings. That would be a massive security risk if any website you visited could just change any OS setting it wanted to.

Comment: I need to disable the ability to apply reacts in my web application that uses webRTC. I assumed that this could be done at the constraints level https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-capture-and-constraints

Comment: That is an OS specific feature that applies to Facetime on a Mac. There isn't even an API for doing this via other video feeds on Mac OS, let alone you being able to hook into this from a web browser. What you want cannot be accomplished this way. You are going to have to look into a custom solution that can apply overlay effects on top of your video feed

Comment: There is currently a bug against Safari for this as apparently it breaks: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=262233